# Parallel file download to USB stick in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, usb-drive

I'm working on a Java application that runs on a USB stick. It downloads multiple files from the server to the sticks and decrypts them. Each file is handled in its own thread. Due to a bug in my previous implementation, the number of threads was not limited, causing some files to end up with 0 KB size when the number of files was high enough (in our test we had 26 small files, a few KB each). The analysis has shown that download failed in this cases, i.e., the decryption had nothing to do, since the files were empty. The typical number of failed downloads in the case was 6. No exceptions have been logged. I also tested the whole process with the application running on the computer directly and the files being downloaded there, too, but the problem never appeared in this case (using Windows 7 and SSD drive).

Having switched to a fixed thread pool with 10 threads, the problem seems to disappear. However, I want to be sure that the problem will not reappear at some point in the future, but I do want to keep the thread pool, since it clearly speeds the whole process up. The question is: how to be sure that I'm not using too many threads? The implementation is supposed to work both on USB 2.0 and 3.0 sticks.

Answer (score 1):

26 is not a big number of threads. If among 26 threads 6 failed to do their job, you definitely have a bug in your program. But neither you nor we do not know what the bug is, so we cannot definitely say if that bug would show itself on a 10 threads.
Worst of all, there is no diagnostics. You should fix your initial program, insert diagnostics everywhere, find the bug and then fix it. After that play with the threadpool size and see if it has an effect on total download time. It well may happen, that 3 or more threads has no advantage over 2 threads.